# Device User Agent Detection | Node.js | express-useragent | Parsing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a log that looks something like this:

```
GET /nands-adblock-logs/a.png HTTP/1.1  http://www.ok.co.uk/celebrity-news/exclusive-stephanie-davis-jeremy-mcconnell-moving-in-together-marriage   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13D15 Safari/601.1
```

My code looks like this to parse the data and return me the user agent:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    useragent = require('express-useragent');


function processFile(inputFile) {
        console.log("INPUT FILE", inputFile);
        instream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile),
        outstream = new (require('stream'))(),
        rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        var ua = useragent.parse(line);
        console.log("PARSED USER AGENT = ", ua);
    });

    rl.on('close', function (line) {
        console.log(line);
        console.log('done reading file.');
    });
}

processFile(process.argv[2]);
```

The output looks like this:

```
PARSED USER AGENT =  { isMobile: true,
  isTablet: false,
  isiPad: false,
  isiPod: false,
  isiPhone: false,
  isAndroid: true,
  isBlackberry: false,
  isOpera: false,
  isIE: false,
  isEdge: false,
  isIECompatibilityMode: false,
  isSafari: false,
  isFirefox: false,
  isWebkit: false,
  isChrome: true,
  isKonqueror: false,
  isOmniWeb: false,
  isSeaMonkey: false,
  isFlock: false,
  isAmaya: false,
  isEpiphany: false,
  isDesktop: false,
  isWindows: false,
  isLinux: true,
  isLinux64: false,
  isMac: false,
  isChromeOS: false,
  isBada: false,
  isSamsung: false,
  isRaspberry: false,
  isBot: false,
  isCurl: false,
  isAndroidTablet: false,
  isWinJs: false,
  isKindleFire: false,
  isSilk: false,
  isCaptive: false,
  isSmartTV: false,
  silkAccelerated: false,
  browser: 'Chrome',
  version: '42.0.2311.133',
  os: 'Linux',
  platform: 'Android',
  geoIp: {},
  source: '"GET /nands-adblock-logs/a.png HTTP/1.1","http://www.ok.co.uk/","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; D2303 Build/18.6.A.0.175) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.133 Mobile Safari/537.36"' }
```

What I'm wanting is to just return the following attributes:

device_type, 
browser, 
OS

How can I retrieve just these values? I'm not so concerned about the values that return false.

Comment: What is the `device_type` you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) for that:

```
_.pick(data, function(value, key) {
  return key === 'browser' || key === 'os' || value === true;
})
```

```js
var result = _.pick(data, function(value, key) {
  return key === 'browser' || key === 'os' || value === true;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
var data = {
  isMobile: true,
  isTablet: false,
  isiPad: false,
  isiPod: false,
  isiPhone: false,
  isAndroid: true,
  isBlackberry: false,
  isOpera: false,
  isIE: false,
  isEdge: false,
  isIECompatibilityMode: false,
  isSafari: false,
  isFirefox: false,
  isWebkit: false,
  isChrome: true,
  isKonqueror: false,
  isOmniWeb: false,
  isSeaMonkey: false,
  isFlock: false,
  isAmaya: false,
  isEpiphany: false,
  isDesktop: false,
  isWindows: false,
  isLinux: true,
  isLinux64: false,
  isMac: false,
  isChromeOS: false,
  isBada: false,
  isSamsung: false,
  isRaspberry: false,
  isBot: false,
  isCurl: false,
  isAndroidTablet: false,
  isWinJs: false,
  isKindleFire: false,
  isSilk: false,
  isCaptive: false,
  isSmartTV: false,
  silkAccelerated: false,
  browser: 'Chrome',
  version: '42.0.2311.133',
  os: 'Linux',
  platform: 'Android',
  geoIp: {},
  source: '"GET /nands-adblock-logs/a.png HTTP/1.1","http://www.ok.co.uk/","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; D2303 Build/18.6.A.0.175) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.133 Mobile Safari/537.36"'
};
</script>
```

With the newest version you would have to replace `pick` with `pickBy`, but plnkr only has the 3.10 version.